# Replicate Function

Tags: sql

```
select rtrim(ltrim(replicate ('PAWANKALYAN                          '  ,  2)))
```

why is this code not removing any white spaces?

Comment: Why do you think that this code doesn't remove white spaces? It remove them from left and right after replicating the string with white spaces two time.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`LTRIM/RTRIM` will not remove **TAB** character. You need to remove TAB spaces using `REPLACE` function

`ASCII` value for tab is `9`. You can use `CHAR(9)` to replace `TAB` character with empty string

```
SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Replace(Replicate('PAWANKALYAN                          '  ,  2),Char(9),'')))
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4976)

Other possible `whitespace` characters other than space are `CHAR(10)`
 & `CHAR(13)`. More info on ASCII values can be found [**here**](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table 
SET    COLUMN =SELECT Replace(COLUMN,'wordreplace','replace with') 
WHERE  COLUMN LIKE '%wordreplace%';
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

Because replicate is causing the spaces not to be on the left and right of the string.

`replicate ('PAWANKALYAN                          '  ,  2)` will yield the string:

`PAWANKALYAN                          PAWANKALYAN                          .` (Without the `.`).

You need to trim *and then replicate*
`select replicate (rtrim(ltrim('PAWANKALYAN                          ')), 2)`

Which will give
`PAWANKALYANPAWANKALYAN` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move replicate out to the outer most part of the nested functions.  The order of nested functions matter.  The trimming has to take place first in this case:

```
select REPLICATE(LTRIM(RTRIM('PAWANKALYAN                          ')), 2)
```